# Passing float values from one view controller to another view controller in ios to show on label

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, label

I want to show float value from previous view controllers label to next view controllers label in ios. Help and guide me regarding the same

Comment: are you using storyboard or xib

Comment: http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers check these threads. Its already been answered multiple times and everybody here would like you to learn by doing .Providing solutions will feed you now but you would never have the taste of self learning

Comment: yes I am using storyboard

Comment: use NSUserDefaults then, you can get the logic by googling

Comment: No, do not use user defaults, that's not what they're for.

Comment: String value I am able to pass but I am not getting how to pass float values

Comment: There's no conceptual difference between passing a float value and passing a string. Show what you've tried.

Comment: My first View Code :

Comment: My first view code :                                                       -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

{

    MainViewController * mc;

    mc = [segue destinationViewController];

 NSString * ch1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",child];

    //mc.Child = ch1.text;

 //NSString *ch1 =[]

    mc.Child = ch1.self;

   // mc.Child= child.text;

    

    

}

Comment: My second view code which i tried                                @implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad { // self.child = self.child1; self.ch1 = _Child;

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's hard to read. Edit your question to include properly formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

1.First import Second view controller to First view controller

2.create float variable in Second view controller

3.at where you are pushing from First to Second view controller,there write code

//in First View Controller

-(ib action)move to second view

{

Second View Controller *sec obj=[Second View Controller new];

sec obj.float variable.text=[self.first label.text float value];

[self.navigation controller push viewcontroller:sec obj animated:nil];

}